# Need to catch ui.router state and its url when the url changes

Tags: angularjs, url, listener, interceptor, angular-ui-router

I wish to attach a listener to URL changes in the `ui.router` module I use in an AngularJS app, because I need to get the `new state` and its `url` when the url changes. In order to customize the url change listener, I've done the following, but it's not working (yet):

in the config section of ui.router, I added this line:

```
$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
```

and after the config(), I have the following code, hoping to cactch the ui.router's state and its url

```
config(
//ui.router's config ommitted....
).run(function($rootScope, $urlRouter) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e) {
          console.log(e);

          e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default handler
          $urlRouter.sync(); //once the interception is done, sync the current url
         $urlRouter.listen();
    })
});
```

I am not sure if this is possible to do with ui.router. Or there is a much easier way to get the `state` and its `url`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what is the real requirement behind. But with UI-Router, we should use `$stateChangeStart` event I'd say.

There is [an example, a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2NKBUSitsEWtkiLk81u?p=preview)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState,   toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) 
{
  console.log(event)
  console.log(toState)
  console.log(toParams)
  console.log(fromState)
  console.log(fromParams)
  console.log(toState)
  console.log($location.url())
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2NKBUSitsEWtkiLk81u?p=preview)

The `$urlRouter` and its `.deferIntercept()` and `.listen()` or more useful for declaring states in a `.run()` phase

```
// config
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider; 

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
      $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();

// run
.run(['$rootScope', '$urlRouter',
  function($rootScope, $urlRouter) {    

    $stateProviderRef
      .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      })
    $urlRouter.listen();
  }
]);
```